# How can I clear browser cache from app in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, caching, npm, forever

I'm using [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to run a Node.js app server.

When I change one of my files (e.g. the router) and refresh the page, I see no change. How can I clear browser cache from my app?

Comment: While you are in the development state of your app you should not use forever but instead use nodemon to automatically restart the server when a file is changed

Comment: thanks it's working fine. but i have a one issue, in my server i have apache an nodejs and when i create server listen to port 80 doesn't work because apache reserve this port. if you have any idea about this issue. thank you very much

Comment: Your nodeJS app must be run on a port different than 80. Usually you set it 3000 and then you configure apache accordingly to reverse proxy to that port

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to refresh your browser with `Shift`+`F5` ([for Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?visit_id=636758507668674696-227395898&hl=en&rd=2)) or `Ctrl`+`F5` (for Firefox) ? So it will ignore the cached content when refreshing.

You can also use [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) as stated in the comments:

> Nodemon is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server.
>   `npm install -g nodemon`